# Why is batchGet not showing any records in the response?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

**Overview:** I am using aws-sdk for javascript to get 2 records from my table "testTable". I have provided the values for the respective keys as well.

**Online Help:** I have followed the documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchGet-property

```
var batchGetItem = function() {
    var params = {
        RequestItems: {
            "testTable": {
                Keys:[
                    {
                        "CaseID": "A1245",
                            "AssignedSupervisorName": "John"
                    },
                    {
                        "CaseID": "A1247",
                        "AssignedSupervisorName": "Bob"
                    }

                ]   
            }
        }
    };
    docClient.batchGet(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "Unable to read item: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "GetItem succeeded: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
            $scope.readData = data;
        }
    });
}
```

The value of **data** is coming as:

```
{
   "Responses": 
   { "testTable": []
   },
   "UnprocessedKeys" : {}
}
```

I was expecting the 2 records to be returned in "testTable" but it is just returning an empty array.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting your table is not created with the keys you are trying to use inside your JS code.

The `keys` inside your `params` should contain only your primary key and sort key of your dynamodb table. You should check whether `AssignedSupervisorName` is set as your table's sort key.

Comment: I have a partition key and sort key. I used readItem function and I was able to get the record. but somehow batch operation is not returning anything